# Divisors of X in set-builder notation

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If I have

```
Divisors of 15
```

The set would be

```
{-15,15,-5,5,-3,3,-1,1}
```

But how would this be written in set-builder notation?

I think it's something along the lines of

```
{x | (15 / x) ∈ N}
```

but that doesn't quite work. Thanks!

Comment: $\{x \in \mathbb{Z} | \exists k \in \mathbb{Z} . kx = 15\}$, this should work. Or as a variation on yours: $\left\{x \in \mathbb{Z} |  \frac{15}{x} \in \mathbb{Z}\right\}$

Comment: @KaiRüsch Thanks! If you post as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use $\{x \in \mathbb{Z} |\ \exists k \in \mathbb{Z}. kx = 15\}$ which uses the definition of "$x$ divides $15$". Or in a similar style to yours; $\left\{x \in \mathbb{Z} |\ \frac{15}{x} \in \mathbb{Z}\right\}$ also works.